# Install device driver inf via command line

Tags: smartcard, hid, inf, sccm

I am working to deploy smart cards to our environment and the driver provided from the manufacturer is 3 files, a CAT,DLL,and INF. If I right click the INF and select install it works. I need to package this for SCCM so I tried to install via command line but I get installation failed every time. Below is the INF

```
 ; 
 ; HID Global Smartcard Minidriver inf for x64
 ;
 ;

 [Version]
 Signature="$Windows NT$"
 Provider=%VendorName%
 DriverVer=07/12/2007,1.0.0.14
 DriverPackageDisplayName="HID Global Minidriver"
 CatalogFile=hidcrdmx.cat
 Class="Smart Cards"
 ClassGuid={990A2BD7-E738-46c7-B26F-1CF8FB9F1391}

 [Manufacturer]
 %VendorName%=HIDGlobal,NTamd64

 [HIDGlobal.NTamd64]
 %HIDGlobalDeviceName%=HIDGlobal_Install,UMDF\ATR_3BFA1800FF8131FE454A434F5034314332303074  

 [DefaultInstall]
 AddReg=Minidriver_RegistryAdd
 CopyFiles=@hidcrdmx.dll
 CopyFiles=Syswow64_CopyFiles


 [HIDGlobal_Install]
 CopyFiles=@hidcrdmx.dll
 CopyFiles=Syswow64_CopyFiles

 [Syswow64_CopyFiles]
 hidcrdm.dll

 [SourceDisksNames]
 1=%MediaDescription%

 [SourceDisksFiles]
 hidcrdmx.dll=1
 hidcrdm.dll=1


 [Strings]
 VendorName="HID Global"
 MediaDescription="HID Global Smart Card Minidriver Installation Disk"
 CardKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\HID Crescendo C200"
 CardKey64="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\HID Crescendo C200"
 HIDGlobalDeviceName="HID Crescendo C200"

 [Minidriver_RegistryAdd]
 HKLM, %CardKey%,"80000001",0x0,"hidcrdmx.dll"
 HKLM,%CardKey%,ATR,0x00000001,3B,FA,18,00,FF,81,31,FE,45,4A,43,4F,50,34,31,43,32,30,30,74
 HKLM, %CardKey%,ATRMask,0x00000001,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff  
 HKLM, %CardKey%,"Crypto Provider",0x0,"Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider"
 HKLM, %CardKey%,"Smart Card Key Storage Provider",0x0,"Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider"
 HKLM, %CardKey64%,"80000001",0x0,"hidcrdm.dll"
 HKLM, %CardKey64%,ATR,0x00000001,3B,FA,18,00,FF,81,31,FE,45,4A,43,4F,50,34,31,43,32,30,30,74
 HKLM, %CardKey64%,ATRMask,0x00000001,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff  
 HKLM, %CardKey64%,"Crypto Provider",0x0,"Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider"
 HKLM, %CardKey64%,"Smart Card Key Storage Provider",0x0,"Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider"


 [DestinationDirs]
 DefaultDestDir = 11 ; dirid = \system32 on WinNT platforms
 Syswow64_CopyFiles=10,syswow64 ; %windir%\syswow64 on x64
```

Comment: Can you share what exactly you specify in program for your package. Which command / arguments? Also it's important whether you targeting x64 or x86 systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dpinst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for installing drivers from the command line. You can get this by downloading the Windows 8 SDK, even if you're not using Windows 8 in the environment. There are separate x64 and x86 dpinst executables. Here is the `dpinst /?` output:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\redist\DIFx\dpinst\EngMui\x64\dpinst.exe
: installs and uninstalls driver packages.
By default, the tool searches the current directory and tries to install all dri
ver packages found.

Usage: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\redist\DIFx\dpinst\EngMui\x64\dpi
nst.exe [/U INF-file][/S | /Q][/LM][/P][/F][/SH][/SA][/A][/PATH Path][/EL][/L La
nguageID][/C][/D][/LogTitle Title][/SW][/? | /h | /help]

  /U INF-file    Uninstall a driver package (INF-file).
  /S | /Q        Silent (Quiet) mode. Suppresses the Device Installation Wizard
and any dialogs popped-up by the operating system.
  /LM    Legacy mode. Accepts unsigned driver packages and packages with missing
 files. These packages won't install on the latest version of Windows.
  /P     Prompt if the driver package to be installed is not better than the cur
rent one.
  /F     Force install if the driver package is not better than the current one.

  /SH    Scans hardware for matching devices and only copies and installs those
drivers for which a device is present. Only valid for Plug and Play drivers.
  /SA    Suppress the Add/Remove Programs entry normally created for each driver
 package.
  /A     Install all or none.
  /PATH Path     Search for driver packages under the given path.
  /EL    Enables all languages not explicitly listed in the XML file.
  /L LanguageID          Tries to use the given language in all UI. Useful for l
ocalization tests.
  /SE    Suppress the EULA.
  /C     Dump logging output to attached Console (Windows XP and above).
  /D     Delete driver binaries on uninstall.
  /SW    Suppresses the Device Installation Wizard, the operating system might s
till pop-up user dialogs.
  /? | /h | /help        Shows this help.
```

If you need to install the publisher certificate before installing the driver, that can be done with `certmgr.exe`, and installing the certificate to the `trusted publishers` store. That way, the driver install won't fail or prompt to continue and it will be truly unattended.

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same situation and in my case, dpinst returned code 0x100 *"No matching devices found"*.

I finally found the solution, using the following command line:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 .\hidcrdmx.inf
```

The C200 is now fully recognized by Windows.

Comment: I get, installation falied